# Swipe.js 2.0 - bind prev and next functions to different Swipe instance callback

Tags: javascript, swipe

I would like two separate elements to slide off a single swipe instance, as far as I'm aware you cant get the touch movement on both at the same time so the solution is to bind the prev and next functions to one of the Swipe callbacks, but I'm not sure how to do this?

If I have two swipe instances, one with a callback:

```
var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipe'), {
  callback: function(index, elem) {
    //WHAT GOES HERE???
  }
});

var slider2 = new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipeTitles'));
```

... how exactly would I bind the second swipe to imitate what the first does?

Answer (score 0):

you could store slider into global variable (this can be achieved by loosing var part) and call next() or prev() manually, based on previously stored current index

```
    var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipe'), {
      callback: function(index, elem) {
        if(currentIndex<index)
             slider2.next();
        else
             slider2.prev();
        currentIndex = index;
      }
    });

/*NO VAR HERE!*/
slider2 = new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipeTitles'));
```